# mysql query by having timestamp along both the axis (i.e) in both columns and rows

Tags: mysql

Consider a table like this:

```
id   name  registration-Date   validity-Date
1      a     2010-10-10          2010-10-25
2      b     2010-10-11          2010-10-26
3      c     2010-10-11          2010-10-27
4      d     2010-10-12          2010-10-25
5      e     2010-10-12          2010-10-25
```

Now I need an output like this:

```
regDate    2010-10-25   2010-10-26   2010-10-27->*(these column names are validity-Dates)*
2010-10-10      1          0           0
2010-10-11      0          1           0
2010-10-12      2          0           0
```

This is my requirement: I just gave 3 registration dates days here. Consider there are N number of registration dates and validity dates. How do I write a query for this?

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to create is called a **pivot table** or **crosstab report**. Here is a link describing how to create a [pivot table in MySQL](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table) and here is a more [in-depth tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/wizard/print_version.html).